# How to modify PK Constraint with of a system-versioned temporal table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio, t-sql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesEmployeeDepartments]
(
    [EmployeeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeDepartmentId] INT NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_EmployeesEmployeeDepartments_UpdatedBy] DEFAULT N'system',
    [FromDate] DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_EmployeesEmployeeDepartments_FromDate] DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(),
    [ToDate] DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_EmployeesEmployeeDepartments_ToDate] DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'),
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([FromDate], [ToDate]),
    CONSTRAINT PK_EmployeesEmployeeDepartments PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId,EmployeeDepartmentId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeesEmployeeDepartments_Employee FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId) REFERENCES Employees([EmployeeId]),
    CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeesEmployeeDepartments_EmployeeDepartment FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeDepartmentId) REFERENCES EmployeeDepartments([EmployeeDepartmentId])
) WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.EmployeesEmployeeDepartmentsHistory));
```

And I am trying to update the PK constraint  to only have 1 field as primary key

I have this post deployment script in my database project

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesEmployeeDepartments]
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_EmployeesEmployeeDepartments

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesEmployeeDepartments]
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EmployeesEmployeeDepartments PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId)
```

When I publish the db project. I am getting this error

```
SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 13557, Level 16, State 1, Line 759 Cannot drop PRIMARY KEY constraint from a system-versioned temporal table 'Employees.dbo.EmployeesEmployeeDepartments'.
```

Comment: You'll have to disable the history (`ALTER TABLE .. SET SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF`), make the change (on both the original table and the history table) then re-enable it. I'm not sure if this would break integrity of the original history; if it does, you'll have to write a query to fix up records (or discard the history if you're not attached to it).

Comment: I would ask why you are trying to do this. If you change this so that the primary key of this table is the primary key of the Employees table then you have created a 1:1 relationship. That means a single employee cannot work for more than 1 department. This is common in the real world where a single person's budget might come from more than 1 department. But if that is the path you are taking why not just add DepartmentID to the Employee table?